# Como funciona a função imagecreatetruecolor? PHP

Tags: php

Chegou numa parte do curso que estou criando um helper para upload de imagens, e tem um exercício que preciso usar o imagecreatetruecolor, mas não entendi muito bem o que a documentação oficial fornece:

```
Cria uma nova imagem true color
```

---

```
imagecreatetruecolor() retorna um identificador de imagem representando uma imagem preta de tamanho x_size por y_size.
```

Como assim identificador de imagem?

Answer (score 3):

Resumidamente poderíamos falar que:

> As funções abaixo fazem parte da biblioteca GD, que por sua vez foi
>   desenvolvida para o tratamento de imagens. Trata-se de uma biblioteca
>   de código aberto para a criação dinâmica de imagens por programadores.
>   A biblioteca cria PNG, JPEG e GIF, entre outros formatos geralmente é
>   utilizada para gerar gráficos, miniaturas, banners...

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php), sintaxe:

```
resource imagecreatetruecolor ( int $width , int $height )
```

**imagecreatetruecolor()** retorna um identificador (resource) que representa uma imagem preta do tamanho especificado. Resumindo:

```
imagecreatetruecolor ($largura ,$altura )
```

Recebe dois parâmetros, ambos são inteiros e retorna um recurso (resource) que será utilizado por outros métodos para dá continuidade ao trabalho de construir uma imagem.

Veja um exemplo contido na [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php):

```
<?php

header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 50)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'Issoé um teste', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Explicando linha a linha:

1. Na primeira linha definimos um cabeçalho ([header](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)) para nossa página, ou seja, será um PNG
2. Utilizamos [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) para criar "a base" da imagem (resource). Resumindo: criamos uma nova imagem true color
3. [imagecolorallocate()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecolorallocate.php) aloca uma cor para uma imagem
4. [imagestring()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagestring.php) — Desenha uma string horizontalmente. É aqui que passamos o resource, informações de que fonte será utilizada, string de texto e cor da fonte
5. [imagepng()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagepng.php) — Emite uma imagem PNG para o navegador ou arquivo
6. [imagedestroy()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagedestroy.php) - Destrói a imagem ("limpa a memória")

Comment: Ainda não ficou claro pra mim como funciona, o que exatamente ela faz e pra que ela serve. Essas informações acima estão no manual, como eu disse, não entendi muito bem. Mas, muito obrigado, Fábio!

Comment: Complementei o post anterior com um paragrafo inicial que pode tirar mas algumas dúvidas.